# The use of 'their' in academic writing

Tags: academic-writing

Is it right to write “big corporations must work on their marketing strategies” in academic writing?
Our instructor said you can't use pronouns like 'their' in academic writing.

Comment: Have you asked your instructor to clarify the reason for this nonsensical edict?

Comment: No-one could possibly find fault with the usage in your *specific* context (***plural*** "they"). But even in the context of a ***singular*** "they" usage, I'd say your instructor is just pointlessly promoting an outdated pedantic position that never really had much going for it anyway.

Comment: It might be time to look for a new instructor.

Comment: I've used both the plural and singular "they" in undergrad papers in Canada, and that was about 10 years ago. No one ever made any comments on it whatsoever, positive or negative, so in my mind it was completely normal. If this rule comes specifically from the instructor giving you assignments, follow it in the assignments. If the question is more about general consensus - no, it's not general consensus, no specific pronoun is prohibited in academic writing.

Comment: Sheesh, I wrote a long comment about style guides and finding ways to push back against an oppressive system and then realized the OP's use in context is totally unambiguously correct in every era to literally everyone.  I'd say that instructor is deeply confused, and possibly trolling.

Comment: I thought this was going to be a question about someone objecting to non-gender-specific pronouns used to represent a single person, but we're talking about *corporations* here?  That's not even controversial - how could anyone have a problem with this?  What other word *would* they suggest?  Because I can't think of anything that would work.

Answer (score 12):

Your instructor probably did not give you such a general guideline. It would be foolish to do so, as your example shows. Your sentence is 100% correct in academic writing and every other kind of writing.

More likely, your instructor is advising you not to match the plural pronouns "they," "them," and "their" to singular antecedents. Here is an example:

> If a person finds some money, they should try to find the owner.

**Person** is singular. The pronoun **they** is plural. People who are very strict about grammar claim that the words are a poor match. So they would say that this example contains an error. If such a person is in a superior position to you (a teacher, a boss) follow their instructions. Use singular pronouns for singular antecedents. Revise the sentence to something like this:

> Someone who finds some money should try to find the owner.

You might want to know, however, that the use of "singular they" has a long history, and most people—including highly educated people—habitually use it in speech. Many academic organizations such as the APA now permit its use in academic writing.

Find out exactly what your instructor meant.

Comment: The only time when it is not academically correct is if it's referring to a specific, known individual. _"Bob works at Company. They're working on Project."_ is confusing if "they" refers to "Bob".

Comment: People who insist that _they_ cannot be singular make exactly as much sense as people who insist that _you_ cannot be singular. (As far as I know there is nobody who makes the latter claim today).

Comment: @forest Weell, in theory we can assume Bob is male and use "he". But gender neutral "they" is just fine now -- "T. Sloane signed of on this, and they have high standards."

Comment: @OwenReynolds "Bob" was just an example name. The point is that there are two kinds of uses of a singular they. One of those has been acceptable for centuries. The other started roughly in the 90s and is still controversial due to the confusion it can cause (many people mistakenly believe that the latter is as old as the former). The example you give is of the latter, but it's not particularly confusing due to its context. My point is not that singular they is unacceptable, just that it _can_ be, depending on context.

Comment: But the subject in this case is "big corporations", which is plural, so "their" is entirely appropriate in this circumstance, and there's really nothing else that would be more appropriate.

Comment: @forest "They" for a known individual isn't controversial due to the confusion it can cause, it's controversial because some people actively oppose acknowledging the existence of trans people (which may include making arbitrary distinctions within their grammar), or they refuse to make even the smallest accommodation for trans people. Pronouns have always carried the risk of being confusing if there are multiple entities they can refer to, this is hardly specific to singular "they". The proper way to avoid confusion is by writing competently, not by avoiding singular "they" altogether.

Comment: @forest But that's not a problem with singular "they", it's a general problem when using a pronoun when there are two entities it might refer to. You run into the same problem with "he", eg in: "Bob works with John. He is currently working on [Project]". Does "he" refer to "Bob" or "John"? In such a case, it would be good to specify or rephrase. But it's not a problem that is (only) related to singular "they".

Comment: @NotThatGuy That's nonsense. There are people who are transphobic, but "they" for a known individual has been controversial long before trans rights were even a point of public discussion.

Answer (score 4):

It is completely correct. Here are some examples of the use of the pronoun "their" to refer to "corporations" in exactly your context:

> "The federal sentencing guidelines for corporations: **Their** development, theoretical underpinnings, and some thoughts about **their** future" [source](https://heinonline.org/hol-cgi-bin/get_pdf.cgi?handle=hein.journals/walq71&section=14)

> … financial executives of multinational corporations, **their** bankers…
>
> ... firms would like to finance **their** foreign subsidiaries [source](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.2307/41164210?journalCode=cmra)

In general, it is common and correct to use pronouns. Indeed correct use of pronouns is *essential* in formal English. If you wrote "big corporations must work on big corporations' marketing strategies" (avoiding the pronoun) this is bad English.